# Report RDLC, report datasource now missing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, rdlc, report

I have to modify one of the reports that our system produces. 
These reports are generated using RDLC files.

I've added the necessary back end to get the info needed for the new field "EmployeeName".

```
//lunchtime report
lunch.Reason = request.SqlDataReaderResult["Reason"].ToString();
lunch.Record_No = (int)request.SqlDataReaderResult["Record_No"];
lunch.Seq = (int)request.SqlDataReaderResult["Seq"];
lunch.EmployeeName = request.SqlDataReaderResult["EmployeeName"].ToString(); // new field
```

But when i do a call in my rdlc file

"=Fields!EmployeeName.Value"

it causes an error:

```
Error   1   The Value expression for the textbox ‘textbox14’ refers to the field ‘EmployeeName’. Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current data set scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified data set scope.
```

I went to try remove the Datasource and re add it for the RDLC, but it is no longer appearing in the list of datasources.

anyone have this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create or modifiy your Dataset file something.xsd so that it matches the new definition.
2. Recreate the Dataset with this new definition.

You're done. When you rebind your DataReader to the report, you won't have the runtime error.